# Mongoimport on mongodb atlas error (eof, connection)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongoimport

This is my command

`mongoimport --host <hostname>.mongodb.net:27017 --db <databasename> --collection <collectionname> --type csv --file <filename>.csv --headerline --authenticationDatabase admin --username <username> --password <password> --authenticationMechanism SCRAM-SHA-1`

And this is the "gift" I receive. First time I try to mongoimport to atlas.

`2021-05-02T20:22:01.292+0300    error connecting to host: could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Single, Servers: [{ Addr: <hostname>.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() : connection(<hostname>.mongodb.net:27017[-61]) incomplete read of message header: EOF }, ] }`

Comment: You are missing the TLS arguments and are attempting a non-TLS connection which doesn't work.

Comment: No it's not about that. When I use --ssl i get :


error connecting to host: could not connect to server: connection() : auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AtlasError) bad auth : Authentication failed

Comment: Right. Authentication happens after connection. So your credentials are also wrong.

Comment: Creds are totally fine and correct. I guess it has to do with having the free cluster maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Seems this error has no obvious and easy answer. I don't know if it's because I have the free tier cluster or maybe some kind of outdated package of mongo cli or it could be literally anything.

So, I just got connected to my cluster via the mongo compass and I did the import with the old fashioned GUI way.

Problem "solved".